Is ChatGPT and LLM killing Stack Overflow
Last few months I have been using ChatGPT LLM for coding, debugging, troubleshooting.
Earlier I used to google / post my question on Stack Overflow.
But now I have instant solution to most of my coding problems.
Does that make Stack Overflow / google irrelevant in the world of LLM (Large Language Model)

yep,  also all coding work in general is irrelevant either now or within the next 3 years as AI gets better...   SMH

But now I have instant solution to most of my coding problems. - ChatGpt and friends are fun, but their "solutions" to coding problems are complete garbage. I hope you scrutinize them well.

@EugeneSh. It is not correct to say it is garbage. I am using ChatGPT for a number of coding related work. The solution given by ChatGPT is really good.

Being able to solve your problem before coming to Stack Overflow is not "killing Stack Overflow".  A great many users could have solved their problems with just some basic debugging, but the existence of debuggers has never killed Stack Overflow.  This community has never sought to be the only source of information, just a useful one.

Stack Exchange, Inc. is doing far more damage on their own than LLMs atm

The fact that this has been asked ad nauseum by techbros and/or Stack Exchange haters ever since ChatGPT first launched nearly 2 years ago, and yet the site is still here, should tell you everything you need to know.

If you have the knowledge to identify if the generated words you get from CrapGPT is crap, chat, or (good) content, then I would question why you're using CrapGPT in the first place. If you don't have that knowledge, then I would question why you're using CrapGPT in the first place. Oh... All avenues lead to the same output.

LLM can't write code. All it can do is slap together statistically likely tokens. If the LLM's database has enough examples of a solution for a problem to be able to reproduce that solution, you get a good solution. But as you get out into the weeds you'll find that the database doesn't have enough information to give a valid solution, but it can get you something that looks convincing and may take you quite some time to find the mistakes.

I do expect programming AI to come along some time soon, and that will transform how we work as programmers. It should be able to eliminate a lot of the scut work and allow the programmer to focus on getting the program behaviour right. Some one has to describe the program behaviour to the computer correctly, and it doen't really matter all that much that's with AI prompts, a traditional programming language, or a combination of the two.

But now I have instant solution to most of my coding problems. I doubt it. More likely is that you come to SO every day you code, multiple times per day.

And if you're doing basic programming and doing older challenges on online judge sites, it's highly likely that you'll have a really good success rate with LLM, but sooner or later you'll get to the bread-and-butter stuff that people will pay for because they couldn't get GPT to spit out anything that worked. Basically, if a robot can do your job, it's only a matter of time before the robot does your job. What do you bring to the table, human?

It's killing the bad (in the context of Stack Overflow) questions. It's a good thing. You are essentially giving a refrigerator review here. Positive reviews about fridges are practically pointless. You don't want to know if they work well when new... you want to know if they work well 8 years down the line. I'd want to see what you have to say about your ChatGPT-driven code a year from now.

Where do you think ChatGPT gets its training data from? If AI gives you a correct answer (and isn't just hallucinating something that looks correct but is actually broken in a way that isn't immediately obvious) it's because a human solved that problem already, quite possibly on Stack Overflow. Which means your question is likely a duplicate, in which case...mission accomplished?

I think this platform is losing momentum. And its because of its gatekeepers - old developers with their ruined normal lives and swolen egos. In 2023 I tried to post to Stackoverflow, stating that one day TypeScript will be added to JavaScript automatically out of the box by AI or whatever. So, JavaScript will become a sort of a language with static typing. You should be their when I posted this supposition, because the Stackoverflow's experts rushed at me and blocked my post. So, the platform is dying not because of AI, but because of being outdated and biased.

@MaksymDudyk "I tried to post to Stackoverflow, stating that one day TypeScript will be added to JavaScript automatically out of the box by AI or whatever" - was this as an answer to a question, or as a question in its own right? Because the way you've phrased it doesn't make it sound like a question.

@f1krazy It was a question I'd like to hear people's opinions about, because I faced difficulty in losing development pace while learning TypeScript I needed community advice. Here is that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78638039/could-javascript-evolve-to-include-compile-time-error-checking

I think this question will be finally upvoted in about 5 to 10 years from now when SO finally declares bankrupcy, because after I played with chatGPT o1-preview it answered all assembly questions I was asking, and explained everything with undestanding that would be only seen in professional developer with years of experience. I was asking about RDNA 3 assembly , something very few people know at the moment.  I upvoted this question.

Short answer: YES, long answer: YES, of course!

Yes, because people want answers immediately which you don't usually get on StackOverflow unless it's a basic question. In addition, they don't want to spend a half hour or more trying to compose a question that fits all the rules of StackOverflow - making sure to show all your research, making sure it's not a duplicate, making sure it's on topic. And ChatGPT will never downvote or close their question.

LLMs are killing Stack Overflow in the same way that fast food killed restaurants. It doesn't.
The page views might be dropping and the ad income with it, so it's still a concern but not necessarily the death.

If anything it's cut down on FGITW questions/answers, since those are usually common and simple enough for a LLM to handle with marginal competence.  But those questions/answers were also probably driving a big chunk of ad views (thus never really being able to get rid of them from a business standpoint even though they were widely considered a plague).

I marveled at Stackoverflow when I found it, but since ChatGPT, I haven't visited it once.

No,  no it doesn't. If you want to be good, you should expand your tools, not limit them.
